# How can I call the functions in the cuSPARSE library in a __device__ function?

Tags: cuda, cusparse

I want to call the sparse matrix multiplication function in cuSPARSE library inside the kernel **instead of** directly calling it at the host side. I write a `__device__` function to implement it.My CUDA is 11.3 and My hardware is V100.My code all follows NVIDIA CUDALibrarySamples:
[spmm_csr](https://github.com/NVIDIA/CUDALibrarySamples/tree/master/cuSPARSE/spmm_csr)

But it fails with:

```
error: calling a __host__ function("cusparseSpMM") from a __device__ function("spmm_csr") is not allowed
```

How can I call it in `__device__` function?

Or there are others ways to implement sparse matrix multiplication inside kernel?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to call the sparse matrix multiplication function in cuSPARSE
> library inside the kernel instead of directly calling it at the host
> side

That is not possible. cuSPARSE is a host only library.

Comment: Thanks！Do you know whether the cuBLAS library is a host only library？

Comment: Yes, cuBLAS is now also  host only. There was a period where there was also a device side version of cuBLAS, but that was discontinued and removed from the CUDA toolkit several major release cycles ago

Comment: @ben286 Some linear algebra features (mostly GEMM) for device code are available through [CUTLASS](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cutlass).